# How to deploy angular app in tomcat webapps sub folder?

Tags: angular, tomcat7, web-deployment

I have created myngapp(angular 7 app) and built it with --prod.
I have already few applications running in my webapps/applications/  directory.

I built myngapp with --baseHref /applications/myngapp/ and --deployUrl /applications/myngapp.
and copy dist/myngapp in webapps/applications directory. When i hit localhost:8080/applications/myngapp, it downloads assets correctly also print test text i added in index.html but i believe AppComponent is not getting bootstrapped. Please help.

Comment: Can you share more details? You are saying your assets are loading, which means your index file is correct. Now the problem arises in the your app module file, can you share all files related to AppComponent. It will be great if you can share codebase since it's just a started.

Comment: isn't it `--base-href`

Comment: Try keeping `<base href='./'>` in your `index.html` file.

Comment: Thanks all. Everything was perfect, somehow i missed rewrite rule configuration to make angular routing work. Apache: add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess file as shown (https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/):